# How to create bootable installer

Tags: mojave, install

I'd like to factory reset my mac (which is running El Capitan 10.11.6), while also updating the operating system. Here's what I've done (i.e. steps from [this website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)) in order to create a bootable installer:

Downloaded the Mojave installer from app store

used `sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume`

When I do this, I get the error message "To use this tool, you must download the macOS installer application on  a Mac with 10.12.5 or later, or El Capitan 10.11.6. For more information, please see the following: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201372"

How can I update the operating system while also doing a factory reset? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the shareware (free) utility https://diskmakerx.com/. I have never had a problem with this. **AND** it involves less typing... ;-)

Comment: How big is the installer you downloaded?  If it's only the stub, you need the complete installer before using createinstallmedia.

Comment: @MarcWilson, I'm sorry, but what do you mean by a stub? I thought I did have the whole installer, since I downloaded it from the app store. Thank you!

Comment: If it's only 22mb, it's the stub, and it downloads what it needs while it installs.  If it's 6gb, it's the full installer.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes it's probably the stub then, I'd guess. How do I access the full installer?

Comment: Thanks @MarcWilson. I was able to install using macOS mojave patcher and then use terminal. probably a bit more cumbersome than necessary, but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation saying MacOS 10.11.6 is wrong as I can't figure how to run that as well. You may need to have a friend run the installer and send you the USB drive with bootable media or perhaps try one last time to reinstall 10.11.6 from this link:

- http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-41424-20191024-218af9ec-cf50-4516-9011-228c78eda3d2/InstallMacOSX.dmg

Sometimes re-installing the same combo updater fixes edge cases or some bit rot / rare damage to existing files. Just because your OS says 10.11.6 doesn't mean everything is in perfect running order.